# ckeditor5 - How to turn off real-time collaboration for some use cases depending on the intended use

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using Angular CKEditor5, I have customized my editor to include RealTimeCollaborativeEditing and PresenceList. For some cases I don't want to use them, so how to turn off it? I don't want to show list of presence, and use real-time.

Example: On page A, I want users to use Collaborative Editing for a piece of content, but on page B it's just a regular editor, not showing list of presence, and use real-time.

I tried to create 2 custom build editors. One is to include RealTimeCollaborativeEditing and PresenceList and the other is not. And then use Editor from 2 different build editors, but I get the error "Packages were duplicated in node_modules"